# Swipe gestures in just 1 scene, how to ignore on other scenes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer, swipe

I have this code in my viewcontroller to move the player in GameScene with swipe gestures:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  var scene:GameMenuScene!
   var scene1: GameScene!
   var scene2: LevelScene!

    let skView = view as SKView
    skView.multipleTouchEnabled = false
    scene = GameMenuScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    skView.showsFPS = true
    skView.showsNodeCount = true
    skView.presentScene(scene)


    let swipeRight:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedRight:"))
    swipeRight.direction = .Right
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedLeft:"))
    swipeLeft.direction = .Left
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeUp:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedUp:"))
    swipeUp.direction = .Up
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

    let swipeDown:UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("swipedDown:"))
    swipeDown.direction = .Down
    view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

    }

func swipedRight(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    let skView = view as SKView
    let gameScene = skView.scene as GameScene
    gameScene.swipedRight1(sender)
}
func swipedLeft(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    let skView = view as SKView
    let gameScene = skView.scene as GameScene
    gameScene.swipedLeft1(sender)
}
func swipedDown(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    let skView = view as SKView
    let gameScene = skView.scene as GameScene
    gameScene.swipedDown1(sender)
}
func swipedUp(sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer){
    let skView = view as SKView
    let gameScene = skView.scene as GameScene
    gameScene.swipedUp1(sender)
}
```

Problem: When I am in another screen than gameScene and I swipe, the game crashes because of "unrecognized selector sent", so I want to use the swipe functions in just the GameScene and not in the LevelScene or GameMenuScene. For the GameMenuScene and LevelScene I want to add other swipe functions.

How do I detect which scene I am in so I can make an if statement?

thank you

Comment: When the current scene deallocates, remove the gesture recognizers. In the new scene, add new gesture recognizers. Otherwise the gesture recognizers will try to send their messages to already deallocated instances of SKScene (the target parameter).

Comment: Thank you, but how do I do that?

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27124314/gesture-recogniser-crashing-upon-next-level/27143060#27143060). It's in Obj-C but easy to convert.

Comment: override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
        for (swipeRight:UIGestureRecognizer  in view.gestureRecognizers){
            [view.removeGestureRecognizer: swipeRight]
        }
    }

I tried this but it gives error, can you help me? thank you

Answer (score 0):

in your GameScene add this...

```
override func willMoveFromView(view: SKView) {
    if view.gestureRecognizers != nil {
        for gesture in view.gestureRecognizers! {
            if let recognizer = gesture as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
                view.removeGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
            }
        }
    }
}
```